# Adding custom styles to Specific theme

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to add some custom stylesheets for specific theme.

for example: 
**Bartik** is default and **Seven** is the Administration theme.

In this case, I want to add some custom styles for only Bartik front-end theme.

How can I customize the following code for the Bartik theme?

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function mymodule_init() {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
    drupal_add_css(
        $path . '/custom.css',
        array(
            'group' => CSS_THEME,
            'every_page' => TRUE,
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what I would do is I would make my own sub-theme that uses Bartik as a base theme and add the additional css stylesheets to my sub-theme's .info file like this:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/MY-CUSTOM-CSS-STYLESHEET.css
```

Just look at Bartik's own .info file to see how it adds stylesheets and javascript files as an example!

Here is some info on how to create a sub theme: http://drupal.org/node/225125.

The best thing about creating a sub-theme rather than adding these stylesheets using a custom module is that you'll be all set to do things like adding or overriding theme images, modifying template files and tackling a big array of potential customizations you may want to do in the future that you may not even be for-seeing now!  It'll just end up being more flexible in the long run.

Comment: My goal is to distinguish between frontend and backend development phases.
and also there are still some bugs on hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter ajax callback. http://drupal.org/node/1296362
I think it would be good to move advanced theme settings into a custom module that is associated with a specific theme.